# Difference between Sympy and Numpy solvers

Tags: numpy, scipy, sympy

I had some problems with `nsolve` having a difficulty to find a solution for some functions giving some initial guesses. I wanted then to try numpy/scipy solvers.

Here is a program using sympy and works quite well giving this solution: `[0.0, -9.05567e-72, 9.42477, 3.14159]`

```
from sympy import *

# Symbols
theta = Symbol('theta')
phi = Symbol('phi')
phi0 = Symbol('phi0')
H0 = Symbol('H0')
# Constants
phi0 = 60*pi.evalf()/180
a = 0.05
t = 100*1e-9
b = 0.05**2/(8*pi.evalf()*1e-7)
c = 0.001/(4*pi.evalf()*1e-7) 

def m(theta,phi):
    return Matrix([[sin(theta)*cos(phi),sin(theta)*cos(phi),cos(phi)]])
def h(phi0):
    return Matrix([[cos(phi0),sin(phi0),0]])
def k(theta,phi,phi0):
    return m(theta,phi).dot(h(phi0))
def F(theta,phi,phi0,H0): 
    return -(t*a*H0)*k(theta,phi,phi0)+b*t*(cos(theta)**2)+c*t*(sin(2*theta)**2)+t*sin(theta)**4*sin(2*phi)**2
def F_phi(theta,phi,phi0,H0):
    return diff(F(theta,phi,phi0,H0),phi)
def G(phi):
    return F_phi(theta,phi,phi0,H0).subs(theta,pi/2)

H0 = -0.03/(4*pi.evalf()*1e-7)
sol = []
for i in range(5):
    x0=i*pi.evalf()/4
    solution = float(nsolve(G(phi),x0))
    sol.append(solution)
sol = list(set(sol)) # remove duplicate values
print sol
```

And this is the same program but using numpy compatible functions:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
# Constants
phi0 = 60*pi/180
a = 0.05
t = 100*1e-9
b = 0.05**2/(8*pi*1e-7)
c = 0.001/(4*pi*1e-7)

def m(theta,phi):
    return array([sin(theta)*cos(phi),sin(theta)*cos(phi),cos(phi)])
def h(phi0):
    return array([cos(phi0),sin(phi0),0])
def k(theta,phi,phi0):
    return dot(m(theta,phi).T,h(phi0))
def F(theta,phi,phi0,H0): 
    return -(t*a*H0)*k(theta,phi,phi0)+b*t*(cos(theta)**2)+c*t*(sin(2*theta)**2)+t*sin(theta)**4*sin(2*phi)**2
def F_phi(theta,phi,phi0,H0):
    return diff(F(theta,phi,phi0,H0),phi)
def G(phi):
    return F_phi(pi/2,phi,phi0,H0)

H0 = -0.03/(4*pi*1e-7)
sol = []
for i in range(5):
    x0=array([i*pi/4]) # x0 as ndarray argument for fsolve
    solution = float(fsolve(G,x0))
    sol.append(solution)
sol = list(set(sol)) # remove duplicate values
print sol
```

But when I ran the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Test4.py", line 27, in <module>
solution = float(fsolve(G,x0))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 127, in fsolve
res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 224, in _root_hybr
raise errors[status][1](errors[status][0])
TypeError: Improper input parameters were entered.
```

I tried giving x0 the value 0 and the second program (with numpy) worked giving a numerical value near to 0, but starting from pi/4, it gives the error message. Did I miss something in numpy ?

Comment: Please do not forget to accept an answer that provides solution to your problem (use the tick next to the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In numpy version function `G(array([pi/4]))` returns an empty array:

```
>> G(array([pi/4]))  
array([], dtype=float64)
```

The problem is in line:

```
return diff(F(theta,phi,phi0,H0),phi)
```

`numpy.diff` calculates differences between consecutive element of the arrays, whereas `sympy.diff` calculates a derivative. You can modify your own `F_phi` function to return derivative calculated  analytically (if you know the solution) or numerically. For numerical solution you can use:

```
def F_phi(theta,phi,phi0,H0, eps=1e-12):
    return (F(theta,phi+eps,phi0,H0) - F(theta,phi,phi0,H0))/eps
```

and analytical solution (calculated with `sympy`):

```
def F_phi(theta, phi, phi0, H0):
    return -H0*a*t*(-sin(phi)*sin(phi0)*sin(theta) - sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(phi0)) + 4*t*sin(2*phi)*sin(theta)**4*cos(2*phi)
```

Please remember that numerical solution won't be as precise as analytical. Therefore, there might be still differences between sympy (analytical) and numpy (numerical) approaches.

Comment: Yes, the problem was coming from the `diff` function, which I thought to be the same in both libraries. Indeed, the solution of numpy seems to be different from that of sympy (although in this last case, the solutions are calculated numerically using `nsolve`, or have I misunderstood the scope of this function?). Besides, depending on the value of eps, I have different solutions: with the value you gave me, I had a warning relative to RuntimeWarning but the set of solutions seem to stabilize for `eps<1e-18`, which is anyway different from the above solution with sympy.

Comment: I added analytical solution, which may be more precise.

Comment: You might also calculate `solution % (2*pi)` because `phi` is periodic. With this modifications `sympy` and `numpy` solutions are very close!

Comment: Yes, SymPy will be symbolic whenever possible. NumPy will never be symbolic.